# Typescript typecasting error while using vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

Typescript typecasting error while using vue.js

```
export interface User {
  id: number
  uuid: string
  email: string
  name: string
  role: number
}

let myObject: User
let otherObject: any
myObject = otherObject as User
```

error code

```
  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
  46 |         let otherObject: any
  47 |         // values are assigned to them, and...
> 48 |         myObject = otherObject as User    // 
  src\components\modal\LoginModal.vue:81:31
          myObject = otherObject as User
```

The ide used is vscode

I do not know why this error is coming.

this is.. used typescript and tslint version

> Version: typescript 2.7.2, tslint 5.9.1

Comment: Resolved. I changed it to .ts instead of .vue extension. Like this... https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript/tree/master/template/src/components/home

Answer (score 0):

Members of [TypeScript interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) have to be semicolon delimited:

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  uuid: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  role: number;
}

let myObject: User;
let otherObject: any;
myObject = otherObject as User;
```

Also, it is recommended that you also always add semicolon at the end of a statement/line, even though they are optional in JavaScript.

I also noticed that it shows an `eslint` error, make sure you are using `tslint` and not `eslint`.

Comment: Thank you... but, my vscode use auto reformat... and semicolon auto remove.. What I have found is an error only when executed in <script lang='ts'>.

Comment: When add semicolon.. eslint show => 4:13 Unnecessary semicolon semicolon i

Comment: @GyuhaShin So are you using eslint or tslint? Try disabling the no-semicolon rule.

Comment: Note, Typescript team are moving to ESLint see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29288